# Quel est le sens précis de la locution « pas plus ... que ... » ?

Tags: expressions

> Je ne révèle jamais mes sources, **pas plus à toi qu'aux autres**.

Se peut-il que cette locution veuille dire « pas aux autres et non plus à toi », ou quelque chose dans ce style ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cela veut dire : « je révèlerai à personne (ni à toi ni aux autres) » avec une accentuation signifiant : « quand bien même tu es mon meilleur ami, je ne te dirai rien ».

Comment: +1, surtout pour parler de "l'accentuation." .... Pour eviter cette accentuation, est-ce que l'on pourrait dire "pas (ni) plus **ou (ni) moins** à toi qu'aux autres" ou est-ce que l'accentuation dont vous parlez (ou meme l'opposante) y serait toujours?  Merci.

Comment: @PapaPoule: Pour éviter cette notion d'accentuation, je dirais : « Je ne révèle jamais mes sources. » tout simplement. Éventuellement complété par « à personne ». Le simple fait de distinguer « toi »  et « les autres » introduit cette accentuation.

Answer (score 0):

On peut reformuler ainsi avec exactement le même sens : « je ne te révèlerais pas plus mes sources que je ne les ai révélées aux autres". Donc ni à toi, ni aux autres...